# How to get Oracle DB connection string

Tags: oracle, reporting-services

I need to connect my Microsoft Report Builder to Oracle DB but I could not seem to find the correct connection string for Oracle.
[image]

I tried:

Specifying username and password

```
Data Source=MyOracleDB;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;Integrated Security=no;
```

but it returned:
[image]

Is it saying that I need to download the Oracle driver? Or should I get the connection string for Oracle DB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't already have it, you will need the Oracle Client installed. It will include an ODBC driver. ODBC is a wrapper for the Oracle Client, not a replacement. When setting up your connection you will also need to get the connection properties from the DBA (e.g. hostname/ip address, port, service name, username and password).

See documentation here:

- https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/adfns/odbc-driver.html
- https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/releasenote-odbc-ic.html